# ArrayList in java difference list

Tags: java

I have created type `String []` in Java, and I want to add elements into it. But since `[]` is a primitive type and I can't add elements into it directly, I have tried to make it an `ArrayList` as well as a `list`, so I wrote `list = ArrayList[]`, but why am I not allowed to do so?

Comment: No, the `[]` notation is used with arrays, which are reference types. Read [this official tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList<String>` is a different data structure from `String[]`.

The declaration

```
String[] arr = new String[10];
```

allocates a fixed-length array of references to `String` and stores a reference to the array in `arr`.  However, the declaration

```
ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

declares an `ArrayList` collection capable of holding a variable number of `String` references.  Most importantly, you can

```
arrlist.add("this is a string");
```

as many times as you want (until you run out of memory).  The operations to put and get values into the collection are different from the array indexing syntax, but all the same operations are provided, with the added benefit that the collection has no maximum size other than available memory.

Here's a link to the [Java Collections Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Comment: In the given UML it says "a: List<String>", does it mean an array( so I can use arraylist), or it means String [], by the way , what's the difference between them.... I always think they are almost the same...

Comment: I thought my answer was pretty clear. An array `[]` has a fixed size while an `ArrayList` expands as you add elements to it.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `ArrayList[]` it is an array of `ArrayList`. Also ArrayList is [generic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java), this is the reason why `list = ArrayList[]` isn't working.

What you need is `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();` and access the values with `String string = list.get(index)`.

Answer (score 0):

String is one type, String[] is other type (array of strings type) and a list of Strings is another type which requires some additional aclarations. Basically you cannot asign an object of one type to a variable of another type.

In a quick guide for your example, Java define an interface named List (java.util.List). But this interface is implemented by several classes (ArrayList, LinkedList, ...). A correct way for use it should be:

```
String[] fixedStrings = new String[3]; // You only can contains 3 strings in it
fixedStrings[0] = "x";
fixedStrings[1] = "y";
fixedStrings[2] = "z";

List<String> manyStrings = new ArrayList<String>(); // List of variable length
manyStrings.add("a");
manyStrings.add("b");
manyStrings.add("c");
manyStrings.add("d");
manyStrings.add("e");

manyStrings.delete(1); // This delete "b" element
```

Then length of a list vary in order you add/delete elements in it. You can check the length of the list invoking its `.size()` method.

I hope this help you,

Regards,

Comment: In the given UML it says "a: List<String>", does it mean an array( so I can use arraylist), or it means String [], by the way , what's the difference between them.... I always think they are almost the same...